# Haskell, troubled typed binding in a simple identity function

Tags: haskell

I have encounter a very strange error while compiling with GHC. This involves a function f.

```
f :: a -> a
f x = x :: a
```

GHC complains that x has an expression type a1, which does not match a.
I do not understand how Haskell's type system works here, is there any explanation? Thank you!

Comment: What is this function supposed to do according to you?

Comment: You probably need the Scoped Type Variables language extension to make this work. Otherwise the two `a` variables don't refer to the same type.

Comment: Yes. Switch on `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`, then do `f :: ∀ a . a -> a` \n `f x = x :: a`. (But also note that in this specific example, the local signature is completely redundant, you might just as well write `f :: a -> a` \n `f x = x` or indeed `f = id`.)

Comment: Ah, I see. So type 'a' is not present inside the function body. Thank you very much!